# Load balancing go servers in Beanstalk

Tags: nginx, go, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm trying to load balance go servers in AWS beanstalk that uses GRPC/Protobuf for data serialization. Beanstalk makes offers nginx as reverse proxy for client-server communication which makes use of http1.1 protocol. This is resulting in bogus messages exchanged between proxy and server but client messages never seem to reach the server as intended. Any clean ideas would help here.

Comment: Why do you need a reverse proxy?

Comment: Apparently, client/server communication on beanstalk works this way. I just have to upload my server code while beanstalk takes care of load balancing using reverse proxy.
Here's the official documentation from Amazon on beanstalk. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/go-environment.html

Answer (score 0):

Nginx doesnt support http/2 to backend yet. Some of us are working on a fix for this but will take another quarter before we could get to upstream it. You can either wait for that or use Envoy (https://github.com/lyft/envoy) in front which supports grpc and http/2 natively. Hope this helps.